# jQuery UI show and hide on hover get interrupted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm currently trying to make a website with a dropdown-navigationbar and I wanted to use jQuery UI to animate the dropping of the bar, using the `.show` and `.hide` methods.

Now, what I want to do is have the drop-down menu .show (using the "blind"-effect) when you :hover it, and when the mouse leaves I want it to hide again.

The problem, however, is that when the blind-effect for show starts, if you mvoe your mouse out of the area at that point it doesn't work. (The event still fires, I tested this using alerts, the animation just doesn't work because the show animation is still going).

I've tried using multiple things like using queue, dequeue, promise.done, but none of these have resolved the issue.

This is how my .js code currently looks:

```
    var nestednavs = $(".nestednav");

nestednavs.mouseenter(function(){
        var ul = $(this).children("ul:first");
        ul.show("blind");
    });

nestednavs.mouseleave(function(){
        var ul = $(this).children("ul:first");
        ul.promise().done(function() {
            ul.hide("blind");
        });
    });
```

Where the nestednav class is assigned to every element with a drop-down menu. As you can see the `promise().done` is still in there, but doesn't actually do anything.

I have tried looking over stackoverflow and general googling but most questions that turned up were for the native jQuery show and hide without the problem of the animation.

I hope I supplied enough information for someone to help me,
thanks!

Comment: Could you wait to execute the code for `mouseleave` until after  the `mouseenter` function is done with something like `$.when`?

Comment: @jonmrich Just tried that with the following code snippet:

http://pastebin.com/QnbWJXMY

However, sadly that did not resolve the issue either. :/ Might there be something I'm doing wrong here?